"apt-get update" failed because unmet dependencies?
every time i use apt upgrade it was error
alr try apt --fix-broken install but still error
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 2.7.14build2) but 2.9.8 is installed
 libapt-pkg6.0t64 : Depends: libgcrypt20 (>= 1.11.0) but 1.10.3-2build1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


Did you run 'apt --fix-broken install' as  suggested ?

What is the output of apt policy apt-utils?

You've not said what Ubuntu release you're using, but your pasted message shows oracular, or you have installed apt | 2.9.8           | oracular        | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x so you've possibly broken your system by unwise changes to your sources; are you running oracular or 24.10 as details match that, some details also matching noble or 24.04 though
